# How to describe 4-8+12-16+20-24+28 using summation ($\Sigma$) notation?

Tags: summation

Can anyone find the ∑ summation for this please?

4-8+12-16+20-24+28

It seems to be going up by steps of 4, but I can't seem to get how I should write it down, since it uses both + and -

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^7 (-1)^{k-1}(4k)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The partial sums$$S_n = \sum_{r=1}^n 4r(-1)^{r+1}$$ are $4, -4, 8, -8, 12, -12,\ldots$. Subtract $1$ to get $3,-5,7,-9,11,-13,\ldots$ which is $(-1)^{n+1}(2n+1)$. Thus
$$S_n = (-1)^{n+1}(2n+1) + 1$$

Answer (score 2):

$$4-8+12-16+20-24+28=4(1-2+3-4+5-6+7)=4((-1)^{1+1}\cdot 1+(-1)^{2+1}\cdot 2+(-1)^{3+1}\cdot 3+(-1)^{4+1} \cdot 4+(-1)^{5+1} \cdot 5+(-1)^{6+1} \cdot 6+(-1)^{7+1} \cdot 7)=4 \sum_{i=1}^{7}(-1)^{i+1}i=4 \left ( \sum_{i=0}^{3} (2i+1)-\sum_{i=1}^{3} 2i\right )=4 \left( 2 \sum_{i=0}^{3} i +\sum_{i=0}^{3} 1-2\sum_{i=1}^{3} i\right )=4 \left( 2 \sum_{i=1}^{3} i +\sum_{i=0}^{3} 1-2\sum_{i=1}^{3} i\right ) \\ =4 \sum_{i=0}^{3} 1=4 \cdot (3+1)=4 \cdot 4=16$$

Comment: Uh...what? Do you think $4\cdot 7$  is $4\cdot (-7)^8$? You've got typos here. Maybe you mean $4\cdot 7\cdot(-1)^8$ instead? I find it incredible that this answer received 4 upvotes.

Comment: Ohh...you're right! I edited my answer..

Comment: How does this help?

Comment: I added some more information at my answer..

Comment: I rather think the OP is asking for a general expression in terms of $n$. (And even if I'm wrong, there are easier ways to evaluate $4-8+12-16+20-24+28$ !)

Answer (score 1):

HINT : For $k\in\mathbb N$, we have
$$(-1)^{2k}=1,\ \ (-1)^{2k+1}=-1.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n 4(-1)^{k+1}k$, for $n\geq1$.

Then

$$S_{2n}-S_{2(n-1)}=4(-1)^{2n+1}2n+4(-1)^{2n}(2n-1)=-8n+8n-4=-4$$

And

$$S_{2n+1}-S_{2n-1}=4(-1)^{2n+2}(2n+1)+4(-1)^{2n+1}(2n)=8n+4-8n=4$$

Hence, for $n\geq 1$,

$$S_{2n}=S_2+\sum_{k=2}^n S_{2k}-S_{2k-2}=-4-4(n-1)=-4n$$

And

$$S_{2n-1}=S_1+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} S_{2k+1}-S_{2k-1}=4+4(n-1)=4n$$

All in all,

$$S_n=4(-1)^{n+1}\left\lceil\frac{n}{2}\right\rceil$$

Where $\lceil x\rceil$ denotes the [ceiling function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions).

Answer (score 0):

This may be redundant coming after TonyK's very nice answer above and answers by others, but here it is anyway.

[image]